# Android Wait For Location Listener Before Continuing With Code

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make a method that sends the users addresss in a text message. (I know how to get the address, and how to send a text message already)

I have created a LocationHelper class that I use to get latitude and longitude and then return an address as a String.

**The issue is that I don't want the sending message code to execute until the address is sent back. How can I delay my code to wait until the address is returned.**

```
    public void sendMessage(){
    String address = // where I call location helper to get address

    // Message is sent using the address string - code below executes before the address is returned - need to delay running the code below
    sending message functionality goes here
    ...
    }
```

I will also want to other methods for example sendEmail(), that will also call the location helper to get the address and  then send an email with the address.
This is why I need to be able to wait until an address is returned before running the sending code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is call a `LocationListener`, and `onLocationChanged` send the message. I think this is easier than using a Location Helper. This would look like:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 70, locationListener);
locationListener = new LocationListener() 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(myContext);
        ArrayList<Address> addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // get the address
        }
        // send the message
```

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to do is use the address for various methods, for example use the address for sending a text, sending an email, opening google maps etc.
This is why I am using the LocationHelper so that I can call it from each method, wait for the value and then do the actions based on what method it is.